# Android Edit Text and Button squeeze view

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

Hi in my android application I have two edittext and one button same like Facebook for login and two textviews in bottom for forgot password and new user. When I enter anything in the first edittext the keybord is hiding the button and the textviews in the bottom. What I need is when keyboard get opened two edittexts and button should be viewable along with the bottom textviews same like Facebook login page.I am giving my code below.. if anyone can help please help me how to do..

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/red">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionContent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginNow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAboutUs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="LOGIN NOW"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>





            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edittext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/editTextPassword"/>



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edittext"
                android:layout_above="@+id/login_Button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"

                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:text="@string/login" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/ifnewuser"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNewUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/newuser"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_red"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/ifforgotpassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewForgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/forgotpassword"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_red"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />` for the same activity in manifest which will help you to adjust the soft keyboard size with the layout views.

Comment: I already given "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden""

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ScrollView` as the parent layout of your View and add

`android:fillViewport="true"` .

Also add this to your Activity in Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

`ScrollView` will appear when your key board opens.

Comment: What is the height of your ScrollView set to?